# SwiftUI: @State doesn't trigger onChange when removing last item from variable

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, onchange

I'm running into what I think is weird behaviour, would appreciate some help.

In the code below (shortened with ... for readability), you will see that when `.append()` or `.remove()` is called, the `onChange(of: sounds, initial: true)"` is called, except when I remove the first value in that array so that its empty [], then its not called.

Is this a glitch? I could have sworn I had this working but I think it has to do with the added `@Binding var sounds` layer I added.

Initially `BSSoundPlayerView` was inside a view and didn't need to be exposed to `BSTabView` through callbacks. But since `BSSoundPlayerView` should be across all tabs, I moved it up a layer and used `@Binding` to bind the tabView with soundPlayerView.

The other issue I'm running into is if I set `isPlaying = true` in `onChange(of: sounds, initial: true)`, the `onChange(of: isPlaying` doesn't get triggered.

```
struct BSTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedSounds: [BSComposerViewSoundType] = []
    @State private var isPlaying: Bool = false
    @State private var showAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var tabSelectionIndex = 1

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            TabView(selection: $tabSelectionIndex) {
                Group {
                    ...
                    BSBackgroundView {
                        BSComposerView(selectedSounds: $selectedSounds, callback: selectedSound)
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Composer", systemImage: "music.quarternote.3")
                    }
                    .tag(1)
                    ...
                }
            }
            if selectedSounds.count > 0 {
                BSSoundPlayerView(sounds: $selectedSounds, isPlaying: $isPlaying)
                    .offset(y: -60)
            }
        }
    }

    // BSComposerView callback
    func selectedSound(_ sound: BSComposerViewSoundType) {
        if let index = selectedSounds.firstIndex(of: sound) {
            self.selectedSounds.remove(at: index)
        } else if selectedSounds.count < 3  {
            self.selectedSounds.append(sound)
        } else if selectedSounds.count >= 3 {
            showAlert.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct BSSoundPlayerView: View {
    @Binding var sounds: [BSComposerViewSoundType]
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @State private var title: String = "Current Mix"
    @State private var showPlayerDetailSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            ...
        }
        .onChange(of: sounds, initial: true) { oldValue, newValue in
            print("onChange(of: sounds, initial: true)")
            guard !sounds.isEmpty else {
                clear()
                return
            }
            let unselectedSounds = oldValue.filter { !newValue.contains($0) }
            for unselectedSound in unselectedSounds {
                clear(soundFileName: unselectedSound.soundFileName)
            }
            guard !newValue.isEmpty else { return pause() }
            play()
        }
        .onChange(of: isPlaying) {
            print("onChange(of: sounds, initial: true)")
            if isPlaying == true {
                play()
            } else {
                pause()
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, for me `onChange` is called when the last item is removed.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yea I could have sworn I had it working. I'm on the last Xcode-beta, that's the only thing I did between yesterday and today. I'm on beta 6 now, and pretty sure it was working in previous betas?

Comment: I am also on the latest beta but be aware I tested this using the simplest possible code so I did not use a TabView for instance so maybe that's part of the issue. And I also didn't have any problem with the second `onChange`.

Comment: I managed to reproduce this by implementing more of your code and it is`if selectedSounds.count > 0` that is the problem because the view disappears when count gets to zero

Comment: One solution is to add the `.onDisappear` modifier to BSSoundPlayerView and do any house keeping there

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for helping me debug this. I actually had that hunch when I encountered this problem. Do you think there is any other option than using `onDisappear`. Because I I end up using it, I'll need to duplicate/refactor that code so it can be used on both methods. I was looking for a modifier to hide the `BSSoundPlayerView` based on `selectedSounds.isEmpty`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I seem to be able to circumvent this issue by creating `@State var showSoundPlayer` and then using that as my conditional check for showing `BSSoundPlayerView `